# Big drop in indexed pages (due to ssl?)

Tags: seo, https

Is it possible to gain a pagedrop because of ssl activation?

[image]

My theory is that it has something to do with the switch to https. Could this be possible?

When I look at content keywords It states the most used keyword is:

[image]

That is certainly impossible since this doesn't appear anywhere on the page.

When I want to tag stuff with the google Data highlighter it doesn't accept it says "This url wasn't found in the google index".

So I checked everything for errors in markup and comited a new sitemap.xml  But it doesn't seem to have any effect??

Does anybody has any idea on how to approach this?

The traffic on the page is still okay. There is no drop there, which makes it even weirder.

Comment: Did you switch from http to https around the same time as the drop?

Comment: And have you put in 301 redirects from the http to https versions?

Comment: No I didn't put 301 redirects in-place because when you enter the address with http it automatically changes to https. Do you think I should have put a redirect to https although it changes automatically?

Comment: You definitely need to check how the http - to - https redirection is happening automatically. Is it a permanent redirection or temporary one. And if it's temporary and the timing coincides...

Comment: You need to add https as a separate property in search console, if you haven't already.  I'm guess the screen shot is for the usual http version of the site. More info here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/03/more-precise-index-status-data-for-your.html

Comment: @Max Thanks for that link. I'd say that was exactly the problem.